# Build Excel from visual ms access from function

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to build a document in Excel from Visual Basic 6 of MS-Access with the following code, which calls the function **TraeDatosCorteAnterior**, which performs a query in the Database, generates the Excel application and adds a Worksheet. Work, however, by continuing to generate the document from the function ** ConstruyeTablayCampo **, the application of an error 424 with the following message ** "An object is required" **:

** Excel object declaration **

```
Option Compare Database
Dim ba As Excel.Application
```

**Initial Funcion**

```
  Public Sub TraeDatosCorteAnterior()

    RstName = "SELECT conc.CP, conc.etapa, conc.total FROM t_conclusion as conc;"
    Dim dbs As Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Dim iRec As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RstOrig As Recordset
    Dim nTotalReg As Integer
    Dim nCP As Integer
    Dim nEtapa As Integer 
    Dim nTotal As Integer

    Set RstOrig = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(RstName, dbOpenDynaset)
    RstOrig.Sort = fldName
    Dim RstSorted As Recordset
    Set RstSorted = RstOrig.OpenRecordset()
    RstOrig.Sort = fldName
    Dim RstSorted As Recordset
    Set RstSorted = RstOrig.OpenRecordset()
    RstSorted.MoveLast
    RstSorted.MoveFirst

    nTotalReg = RstSorted.RecordCount

    nCP = RstSorted("CP")

    nEtapa = IIf(IsNull(RstSorted("etapa")) = True, 0, RstSorted("etapa"))
    nTotal = IIf(IsNull(RstSorted("Total")) = True, 0, RstSorted("Total"))

    RstSorted.MoveNext


    Set ba = New Excel.Application
    Set xlwbook = ba.Workbooks.Add
    ba.Visible = True

    ConstruyeTablayCampo "Cuadro I", "Cuenta Pública", "A", "A", ba, False, 1

  End Sub
```

** Function that builds the document **, from the first line marks the error.

** Excel object declaration **

```
 Sub ConstruyeTablayCampo(ByRef sHoja As String, ByRef sTexto As String, ByRef col1 As String, ByRef col2 As String, ByRef ba As Excel.Application, Optional bCreaHoja As Boolean, Optional nHoja As Integer)

        Set xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets.Item(nHoja)
        xlwbook.Sheets.Item(nHoja).Name = sHoja

        xlsheet.Cells.Range("A11:A11") = sTexto
        Worksheets("Cuadro I").Range("B:B,D:D,H:H,J:J,N:N,Q:Q").ColumnWidth = 1

        With xlsheet.Cells.Range(col1 & "11:" & col2 & "12")
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .WrapText = True
                .Select
                .Font.Bold = True
                .MergeCells = True
                .Interior.Color = RGB(244, 244, 244)
        End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance, I hope you can help me!

Comment: I don't think you mean VB6  which was for standalone programs, but VBA.

Comment: Where is `xlwbook` declared?  Start by adding `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, and fix anything flagged by that.

Comment: xlSheet isnt declare either.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolve it, the solution was do this:

**First declare this**

```
Option Compare Database

Dim ba As Excel.Application
Dim xlwsheet As Excel.Worksheet
```

Second initialize the object in the second line:

```
 Sub ConstruyeTablayCampo(ByRef sHoja As String, ByRef sTexto As String, ByRef col1 As String, ByRef sRango1 As String, ByRef col2 As String, ByRef sRango2 As String, ByRef ba As Excel.Application, ByRef color1 As String, ByRef color2 As String, ByRef color3 As String, ByRef nHoja As Integer)

        Set xlwsheet = ba.Worksheets.Item(nHoja)
        xlwsheet.Name = sHoja
        xlwsheet.Range("B:B,D:D,H:H,J:J,N:N,Q:Q").ColumnWidth = 1

        With xlwsheet.Cells.Range(col1 & "11" & ":" & col2 & "12")
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .WrapText = True
                .Select
                .Font.Bold = True
                .MergeCells = True
                .Interior.Color = RGB(color1, color2, color3)
        End With

        xlwsheet.Range(col1 & "11:" & col2 & "12").Cells = sTexto

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!